# Rails 3 - How do you create a new record from link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, belongs-to, link-to

I'm trying to create a 'tag' functionality which allows a user to "tag" items in which they are interested.  Here is my model

```
class tag
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end
```

The corresponding DB table has the necessary `:user_id` and `:item_id` fields.

In the list of `:items` I want a link next to each `:item` that allows the user to tag the `:item`.  Since I know the `:user_id` and the `:item_id`, I want to create a new `:tag` record, set the id fields, and save the record - all with no user intervention.  I tried the following call to `link_to` , but no record is saved in the database:

```
<%= link_to 'Tag it!', {:controller => "tracks", 
                       :method => :post, 
                       :action => "create"},
                       :user_id => current_user.id, 
                       :item_id => item.id %>
```

(This code is within an:  `@item.each do |item|`  statement, so item.id is valid.)

This `link_to` call creates this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/tags?method=post&tag_id=7&user_id=1
```

Which does not create a `Tag` record in the database.  Here is my `:create` action in the `tags_controller`

```
 def create
    @tag = Tag.new
    @tag.user_id = params[:user_id]
    @tag.tag_id = params[:tag_id]
    @tag.save
  end
```

How can I get link_to to create and save a new tag record?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The very fact that the generated URL has method as parameter implies it's doing a GET and not POST.

The link_to signature you must be using is `link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})`

```
<%= link_to 'Tag it!', {:controller => "item", 
                       :action => "create", 
                       :user_id => current_user.id, 
                       :item_id => item.id},
                       :method => "post" %>
```

:method should be passed to html_options and rest to url_options. This should work.

Comment: Thanks!  It works great with your fix.  Showing the link_to signature in your answer really helped me finally understand what was going on.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick comment. In the url_options hash the controller key's value should be "items" not "item". It would give you an ActionController routing error when trying to display the link.

Comment: @dexter, what happens if the link is outside of the app, like in an email, for example? My use case is for RSVPs. I want to create a new RSVP directly from the email link, but I want to stay RESTful.