# Rails simple_form pre-populated input values lost during server side form validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a simple_form in my rails app that I want to pre-populate
some of the fields with URL parameters.

Example URL is:

```
http://localhost:3000/surveys/new?phone=8675309
```

This pre-populate the phone field corretly using this code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @survey, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<%= f.input :state, :required => true %>
<%= f.input :zip, :required => true %>
<%= f.input :phone, :required => true, :input_html => { :value => params['phone'] } %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is if the form is submitted without a required field
the form is reloaded but the phone input value is not retained.

If the form is submitted without a value for zip
the reloaded page with validation errors in red URL is now:

```
http://localhost:3000/surveys
```

If, say, the state field is correct but no zip code the form is reloaded
with an error msg saying zip is required.

The state value is retained however the phone is not.

I guess it has to do with :value => params['phone'] in the f.input for the phone.

Is there anyway I can populate the simple_form with URL paramenters
on it's initial load and have those value retained if the serverside validation fails?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mark,

I re-posted this question again a while back and it was answered corretly here:

[Rails simple_form server side validations lost URL params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036381/rails-simple-form-server-side-validations-lost-url-params)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `:value` from your view:

```
<%= f.input :phone, :required => true %>
```

and use this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/surveys/new?survey[phone]=8675309
```

That should generate the "standard" `survey` parameter hash expected by the controller. In my test, that works the same as if the user had typed in the value, with the usual validation handling.

Inside the controller, the hash is called `params[survey]` with individual parameters  represented as `params[survey][phone]`, `params[survey][zip]`, etc.

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7219342/550712), I found that you can generate the URL with the link_to signature `link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})`:

```
<%= link_to 'New survey', { :controller => "surveys", 
                            :action => "new", 
                            :survey => { :phone => "8675309", :zip => "10001" } },
                          { :target => "_blank" } %>
```

Note that `url_options` is the first hash, and within that hash you have a `survey` hash for pre-loading values. Finally comes the optional hash of `html_options` (where I added `target="_blank"` for illustration purposes).